# Confusion regarding the trial solution taken in the mathematical treatment of forced oscillations, at steady state

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, complex-numbers

In the text-book that I am currently using, it is given that in case of forced oscillations, the periodic external driving force is a complex-driving force, and is generally of the form $F_0e^{jwt}$.

However, more particular expressions for the driving force, such as $Re(F_0e^{jwt})=F_0\cos{\omega t}$, or, $Im(F_0e^{jwt})=F_0\sin{\omega t}$, could also be used.

So, the solution $x$ is also taken accordingly as $X_0e^{jwt}$, or, $Re(X_0e^{jwt}) = X_0\cos{\omega t}$ or, $Im(X_0e^{jwt})=X_0\sin{\omega t}$.

According to the book, the derivative of $Re(X_0e^{jwt})$, w.r.t $t$ (i.e., the velocity of the oscillator) is given by $Re(jwX_0e^{jwt})$.

It is known, that $X_0$ is independent of $t$, and dependent on $w$, and, is complex-valued.

Is $Re(jwX_0\exp(jwt))$ the same as $jwRe(X_0\exp(jwt))$?

Probably not, but I cannot think of a suitable mathematical explanation.

Comment: unless $w$ is pure imaginary, then those two expressions are obviously not equivalent.

Comment: Take number 1, number 1 is real, $Re(1)=1$. Now multiply it by $j$, you have $j \cdot 1$, is the real part of the result $j Re(1)$? Clearly not, that's because you cannot take out complex numbers out of $Re$ and $Im$.